# How to remove duplicates from array of objects and combine values of that duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have array like this, my `id` and `name` will be same for multiple objects but `organizations` values can be different

```
array= [
  {id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 1},
  {id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 2},
  {id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 3},
  {id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 4},
  {id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 5},
  {id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 6} 
];
```

I want to convert this to be like this:

```
expectedArray =  [
  {id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: [1,2,3]},
  {id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: [4,5,6]} 
];
```

Can someone please help

Comment: What if two objects have a common `id` but different `name`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge duplicate objects in single array using lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485761/merge-duplicate-objects-in-single-array-using-lodash)

Answer (score 3):

```js
const array= [
  {id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 1},
  {id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 2},
  {id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 3},
  {id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 4},
  {id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 5},
  {id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 6} 
];

const mergeDuplicates= (field, uniqueField) => (source = [], value)=> {
    const target = source.find( item => item[uniqueField] == value[uniqueField] );
    if(target) target[field].push( value[field] );
    else source.push({...value, [field]: [ value[field] ] });
    return source;
}
const mergeOrganaizationsById = mergeDuplicates('organizations','id')
const result = array.reduce(mergeOrganaizationsById, [])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to reduce.

```
array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const i = acc.findIndex(a => a.id === cur.id && a.name === cur.name);
  if (i === -1) return [...acc, {...cur, organizations: [cur.organizations]}];
  return [...acc.slice(0, i), {...cur, organizations: [...acc[i].organizations, cur.organizations]}, ...acc.slice(i +1)];
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the output using `forEach` by grouping based on `name` and then pushing the necessary fields into the output array.

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 1 },
  { id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 2 },
  { id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 3 },
  { id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 4 },
  { id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 5 },
  { id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 6 }
];

const current = Object.create(null);
const finalArr = [];
array.forEach(function (o) {
  if (!current[o.name]) {
   current[o.name] = [];
   finalArr.push({ id: o.id, name: o.name, organizations: current[o.name] });
  }
  current[o.name].push(o.organizations);
});
console.log(finalArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one solution in kind of **ES6** style

```js
const array= [{id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 1},{id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 2},{id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 3},{id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 4},{id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 5},{id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 6}];

const result =  Object.values(array.reduce((acc, { id, name, organizations }) => {
  const hash = `${id}-${name}`;
  acc[hash] = acc[hash] 
    ? { ...acc[hash], organizations: [...acc[hash].organizations, organizations] } 
    : { id, name, organizations: [organizations] };
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like this solution best. The only thing you'll have to look out for is the hash construction, if there are dashes in either field you can end up with false matches.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the easiest way to tackle this problem, only using the forEach and basic arrays' method.

I hope I answered your question.

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 1 },
  { id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 2 },
  { id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 3 },
  { id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 4 },
  { id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 5 },
  { id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 6 }
];

const newArr = [];

// for keeping track for added item
const addedItems = [];

// for keeping track of added item idx
let addedItemIdx = 0;

array.forEach((item) => {
  if (!addedItems.includes(item.id)) {
    let tempOrg = item.organizations;
    newArr.push({ ...item, organizations: [tempOrg] });
    addedItems.push(item.id);
    addedItemIdx++;
  } else {
    newArr[addedItemIdx - 1].organizations.push(item.organizations);
  }
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a hashmap. You can read about them but the basic idea is that you make a key,value pair and access to the data with keys is very efficient(O(1) amortized). So here is one way to solve this problem in python. I am sure you can use it to solve it in your language.

```
    array= [
  {"id": 1, "name": "Test1", "organizations": 1},
  {"id": 1, "name": "Test1", "organizations": 2},
  {"id": 1, "name": "Test1", "organizations": 3},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Test2", "organizations": 4},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Test2", "organizations": 5},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Test2", "organizations": 6}
]
# Initilize a hashmap
hash_map = {}
# Loop over all the items in array and create the hashmap
for item in array:
    # key will be id and name as both are needed to group the organizations
    # We have use comma to separate them as we assume that name or id cannot have comma
    key = str(item["id"])+","+item["name"]
    # IF key is already present then add the new organizations id to it
    if key in hash_map:
        hash_map[key].append(item["organizations"])
    # Else make a new list with the current organizations id
    else:
        hash_map[key] = [item["organizations"]]

# Create the expected array
expected_array = []
for key,value in hash_map.items():
    # Get the id and name by spliting the key that we created 
    idx,name = key.split(",")
    expected_array.append({"id":idx,"name":name,"organizations":value})
print(expected_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Test1",
    organizations: 1
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Test1",
    organizations: 2
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Test1",
    organizations: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Test2",
    organizations: 4
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Test2",
    organizations: 5
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Test2",
    organizations: 6
  }
];


const formattedData = array.reduce((result, {
  id,
  name,
  organizations
}) => {
  let filteredRow = result.find(row => row.id === id && row.name === name);
  const org = filteredRow ? filteredRow.organizations : [];
  org.push(organizations);
  filteredRow = {
    id,
    name,
    organizations: org
  };
  if (org.length === 1) result.push(filteredRow);
  return result;
}, [])

console.log(formattedData)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 1 },
  { id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 2 },
  { id: 1, name: "Test1", organizations: 3 },
  { id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 4 },
  { id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 5 },
  { id: 2, name: "Test2", organizations: 6 }
];

const result=array.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  const id=curr.id;
  const {organizations}=curr;
   const findIndex=acc.findIndex(item=> item.id===curr.id)
  if(findIndex===-1){
    acc.push({...curr,organizations:[organizations]});
  } else {
   
    acc[findIndex].organizations.push(curr.organizations)
  }
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Test1",
    organizations: 1
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Test1",
    organizations: 2
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Test1",
    organizations: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Test2",
    organizations: 4
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Test2",
    organizations: 5
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Test2",
    organizations: 6
  }
];
const reducedArray = array.reduce((resultArray, arrayElement) => {
  const elementIndex = resultArray.findIndex(element => element.id === arrayElement.id);

  if (elementIndex !== -1) {
    resultArray[elementIndex].organizations.push(arrayElement.organizations)
  } else {
    resultArray.push({
      ...arrayElement,
      organizations: [arrayElement.organizations],
    });
  }
  return resultArray;
}, []);

console.log(reducedArray)
```